# Why do not I get the id when mapping from DTO to entity with mapstruct?

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I have an API with spring boot and I use mapstruct and I just want to update the Person entity. For this, having PersonDto update Person.

What I have so far:
Mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
   PersonDto toPersonDto(Person person);
   Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto);

   Person updatePersonFromDto(PersonDto persoonDto, @MappingTarget 
      Person document);
}
```

1. In service layer:
   Find Person:

   ```
   public PersonDto updatePerson(Long personId) {

     PersonDto personDto = personService.findById(personId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new PersonNotFoundException(id));

     personDto.set(...) //set others properties

     Person person = personMapper.toPerson(personDto);
     person = personMapper.updatePersonFromDto(personDto, person);
     personRepository.save(person); 
     return personMapper.toPersonDto(person);
   }`
   ```

My question, is there a strategy or a better way of update an entity from a DTO?

Edit:
I was able to solve a part, now I do not lose the id, but I still create a new object instead of updating it. The id is in AbstractPersistableEntity.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person extends AbstractPersistableEntity<ID> implements Serializable {
  @Column
  private String name;
  @Column
  private String lastName;
  @Column
  private Integer age;
}

public class PersonDto {
   @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String lastName;
   private Integer age;
}
```

Comment: The mapper is generated so what would you want to improve in this code?

Comment: Do not lose the id by mapping the DTO to the entity so in that way to be able to update the entity in database instead of creating a new tuple.

Comment: Could you show us the code of Person and PersonDto and any specific setting that could change the mapper behavior?

Comment: I updated the mapper also.

Comment: I would try to implement setter and getter for id in Person and call the super.set and super.get. To see if it's work. It should be related to the extends AbstractPersitableEntity. I guess mapstruct can't understand that Long Id in PersonDto has to be mapped to id in AbstractPersistableEntity

Comment: In this case you may have to implement your own mapper

Comment: I'm in it, thanks for helping!

Comment: I guess a miss a few steps in your example: e.g. getting the entity from the DB and storing it again.  Please extend your question with this. Also: I would not use, setters, getters in combination with a builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not the most optimal or correct solution but it works. I made the following modifications to the mapper:

```
 @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE,
        nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
Person updatePersonFromDto(PersonDto persoonDto, @MappingTarget 
  Person document);

 @ObjectFactory
 default Person updatePerson(PersonDto personDto, Person person){
    if (personDto != null){
        Long id = person.getId();
        Person resultPerson = updatePersonFromDto(personDto, person);
        resultPerson.setId(id);
        return resultPerson;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then from the service just call:

```
person = personMapper.updatePerson(personDto, person);
```